# Regex to match 0 to 9 Arabic int

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will only allow Arabic integers from 0 to 9 (no spaces, decimals, nothing... just numbers 0 to 9). I'm using it part of replace function, so in reality I want to look for anything that does not fit in the 0 to 9 Arabic int criteria, and remove it.

I'm using the following regex but it leaves spaces, and I'm not sure if it only allows Arabic integers.

```
[^0-9]+$
```

Any idea how to modify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a regex to validate a string, your `^` should be outside the square brackets. Having it inside means "find characters that **aren't** 0 to 9". Having it outside makes it a start anchor.

```
^[0-9]+$
```

**EDIT:** if you're performing a regex replacement, remove the `$` so you can remove non-integers that are anywhere in a string:

```
[^0-9]+
```

Comment: that still does not remove the space... :/ 1234 5678 comes back as 1234 5678 with the space intact... I'm using a rereplace() function

Comment: @Mohamad: Ah then that changes things... see my edited answer.

Comment: Duhh... I feel stupid now... what since I'm using a rereplace function, my function was looking to match everything that's not 0 to 9... so it was correct in the beginning... but the space issue is still there...